# Can the order of std::shuffle depend on anything but the RNG?

Tags: c++, random, language-lawyer

For shuffling two vectors in the same order, it's tempting to do something like

```
whatever_rng_type rng2(rng1);

std::shuffle(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), rng1);
std::shuffle(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), rng2);
```

where identical RNG states are used for the two shuffles. However, I don't see any requirement that these shuffles actually produce the same order in the [standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) I checked.

`std::shuffle` must use the provided RNG as its source of randomness, but the implementation might also do something like take a different code path for different element sizes. Maybe an implementation might use AVX512 gather/scatter instructions for some types and a generic, non-vectorized code path for others, and that could affect the result ordering.

Is performing two shuffles with the same seed actually a safe way to get the same order? Is there something I missed in a later standard version, or a defect report or something?

Comment: FWIW, assuming the vectors have the same length, you could consider populating a vector with integers `0` .. `vec1.size() - 1`, shuffling that, and using it to index into `vec1` and `vec2`.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Yeah, but sometimes you really do need to physically reorder the vectors (and physically reordering them using a shuffled index vector is expensive and awkward compared to a direct shuffle). What I'd really like is some sort of `pair_thing(vec1, vec2)` backed by the original two vectors, where shuffling the pair thing automatically shuffles the original vectors together.

Comment: I double-checked the Standard and agree there's nothing requiring `shuffle` make any guarantees about its use of random numbers.  It simply remarks _"To the extent that the implementation of this function makes use of random numbers, the object referenced by g shall serve as the implementation’s source of randomness."_.  So, the remaining question seems to be whether you're interested in implementation-defined or -observed behaviour for any specific implementation(s), or will stick to a Standards-compliant portable solution (e.g. shuffling proxy objects or using an array of indices)...?

Comment: Your question asks what the standard guarantees something, but then your comment says you're looking for a solution. These are different questions, leading to the confusion below. If you do want to ask both questions together, then edit the question. Also, are you fine with library solutions? boost, and range-v3 will let you get the effect you want in a couple of lines, with efficiency.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Not sure I agree that it’s inefficient — there are O(n) algorithms for reordering, so it’s asymptotically as efficient as sorting twice (but requires O(n) additional storage).

Answer (score 2):

I double-checked the Standard and agree there's nothing requiring shuffle make any guarantees about its use of random numbers. It simply remarks:

> "To the extent that the implementation of this function makes use of random numbers, the object referenced by g shall serve as the implementation’s source of randomness.".

So, the remaining question seems to be whether you're interested in
implementation-defined or -observed behaviour for any specific
implementation(s), or will stick to a Standards-compliant portable
solution (e.g. shuffling proxy objects or using an array of
indices)...?

Based on your comments, it seems you're opposed to the array-of-indices suggestion, so below - an implementation of using custom iterators and proxies to shuffle the vectors themselves...

(Not done very carefully - more a proof of concept / illustration, so check carefully before using for anything important....)

The approach requires a `move_together` object that keeps references to the vectors, and then passes `shuffle` `iterator`s that have a pointer to the `move_together` object and an index in the vectors being processed.  You could arguably simplify this by foregoing the `move_together` object and having pointers or references to both vectors directly in the iterators.  When the iterators are dereferenced, they return proxy objects that then support `swap`ping.

It ostensibly works with GCC 10.2 and clang 10, but there could be a different implementation of `std::shuffle` for another compiler that requires a more fully fleshed out iterator or proxy....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct move_together;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct proxy
{
    const move_together<T1, T2>* p_;
    const size_t i_;
    proxy& operator=(const proxy& rhs);
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct move_together
{
    move_together(std::vector<T1>& v1, std::vector<T2>& v2)
      : v1_(v1), v2_(v2)
    { }
    struct iterator
    {
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = ssize_t;
        using value_type = proxy<T1, T2>;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using reference = value_type&;

        const move_together* p_;
        size_t i_;
        value_type operator*() { return {p_, i_}; }
        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const { return i_ == rhs.i_; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& rhs) const
           { return i_ - rhs.i_; }
        iterator operator+(int distance) const
           { return {p_, i_ + distance}; }
        iterator operator++(int) { auto x = *this; ++i_; return x; }
        iterator& operator++() { ++i_; return *this; }
    };

    iterator begin() { return {this, 0}; }
    iterator end()   { return {this, std::min(v1_.size(), v2_.size())}; }
    std::vector<T1>& v1_;
    std::vector<T2>& v2_;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
proxy<T1, T2>& proxy<T1, T2>::operator=(const proxy<T1, T2>& rhs)
{
    p_->v1_[i_] = rhs.p_->v1_[rhs.i_];
    p_->v2_[i_] = rhs.p_->v2_[rhs.i_];
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void swap(proxy<T1, T2> lhs, proxy<T1, T2> rhs) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.p_->v1_[lhs.i_], rhs.p_->v1_[rhs.i_]);
    swap(lhs.p_->v2_[lhs.i_], rhs.p_->v2_[rhs.i_]);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} };
    std::vector<std::string> v2{ {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"} };

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng{rd()};

    move_together m{v1, v2};
    std::shuffle(m.begin(), m.end(), rng);

    for (const auto& x : v1) std::cout << x << '/';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (const auto& x : v2) std::cout << x << '/';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a different question.

Comment: @Barmar seems to be answering [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64012057/can-the-order-of-stdshuffle-depend-on-anything-but-the-rng#comment113201282_64012057)

Comment: I've confirmed OP's understanding that the Standard provides no guarantees that his approach will work in comments (but will copy/paste my comment here for good measure), and this provides an implementation for his functional requirement in O(1) space and without a clumsy third vector of indices that would need to be used afterwards.